# Branch if condition is true in AArch64

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I am trying to implement some conditional instructions in AArch64 assembly instructions. I know this architecture has less conditional instructions compare with AArch32 because of better compiler optimizations. However, I have to implement this logic in my code.
First: I want to jump into label `nomod` when the value in `xn` register is less than the value in `xm` register, I came up with these instructions so far:

```
"cmp x7, x16 \n\t"
"b.ls nomod%= \n\t"
...some instructions....
"nomod%=: \n\t"
```

I don't get any error but I am not sure if it is possible to implement this logic like this.

Second, I want to jump into label `nomod` when the carry flag is set to `1`. Based on this [tutorial](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801a/DUI0801A_armasm_user_guide.pdf), I should be able to do this as the following:

```
...some instructions...
"b.c nomod%=\n\t"
...some instructions...
"nomod%=: \n\t"
```

But, I've got `unknown mnemonic "b.c nomod70"`.

Comment: The correct mnemonic is `b.cs` for `carry set`.

Comment: @Jester Ah thank you very much. What about the first one? Is that correct?

Comment: `LS` is `lower or same` and you said you wanted `less than` so the correct one is `LO`. See [Condition code suffixes and related flags](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801d/dom1359731161338.html)

Comment: The flags and condition codes are no different from AArch32, they're just applicable to fewer instructions...